# Remove icon in Nested Menu Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

i would like to ask, how to remove arrow icon in nested menu.
i took from this example https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

[image]

I would like to remove arrow icon on the right side after Redial name.

anyone have idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i finally found it

```
.mat-menu-item-submenu-trigger::after {
   border-style: unset !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details, to show that this css works ?

Comment: what detail do you need ? it overloads the css property of the native submenu trigger.
Just copy past it in your css file

Comment: This is not working, can you please provide an alternate solution?

Comment: is your css class accessible to your component ? 
works well for me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDjG0.png

Comment: menus are rendered inside body using overlays like dialogs. So if you want to customize it you have to do w/o view encapsulation or using ng-deep.

Comment: .mat-menu-submenu-icon {
  visibility: hidden;
}

Answer (score 0):

To remove the icon, add below css in global styles (styles.css / styles.scss)

```
.mat-menu-submenu-icon {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```